# Does watson discovery support french?

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I try on bluemix the service only propose German, Spannish, English, but maybe it's beacause of the free plan.

Comment: It currently only supports English, Spanish, or German. See: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/building.html#preparing-the-service-for-your-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full French support is currently expected in 2018.